# Delete users registered via social login when they are deleted in Login Provider

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

We have a system that supports social logins and we have a feature that users can download api access key and secret key to make APIs programatically.

But when a user account is deleted from social login provider the user can't login in the system. But the same user can access APIs programmatically. Is it possible to stop the API login as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be done, unless the social service supports publishing some kinds of events about deleted users (though I highly doubt that anyone would be doing that). Maybe there is another way to verify for you whether a given account exists in the social service (by calling some endpoint, for example). Then you can periodically check with this endpoint which of users exist. Or call this endpoint when you get a request to the API and verify if the user still exists.

Comment: Is it wise storing refresh token and try periodically verify it?

Comment: If the server which refreshes tokens is the same which verifies logins, then yes. But very often you the Authorization Server (which issues tokens) is not the same as the social service which provides login information. From the latter you usually get ID tokens, which can't be refreshed.